# Infinity Blade 2 on my Ipod

Tags: infinity-blade-2

When I download the game Infinity Blade 2 on my Ipod, I open it and it appears to me that the Ipod sensed a saved progress of the game. It was my first time playing Infinity Blade 2 on my iPod and it has a saved game. Why is that? Also, when I play the game, it is very laggy on my iPod but not on my familiy's iPad.

Comment: Have you purchased the game on a previous device under the same AppleID? That's probably it. For why it's laggier on your ipod, well, there's numerous reasons behind that.

Comment: turn off icloud(that will fix save problem). try cleaning space(will fix lag problems)

Comment: @iMAGEbox Comments are for clarification, answers are for answers. Please stop putting answers in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that someone played it first on the iPad? Then the saved game transferred to your iPod through iCloud.

As for the lag, it is probably due to the hardware, your iPad must have better components than your iPod. You can compare them in this [list of iOS devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices).

Answer (score 0):

turn off or delete icloud on infinity blade(that will fix save problem). try cleaning space(will fix lag problems)